# Undefined index error

Tags: php

I understand `explode` has nothing to do with the `my_sql` and `PDO`. I have a silly doubt and wondering if someone can explain me this.

I have a XML file which I am parsing for a particular tag (script) which has data like -

```
scripts/testSuite/UTA/CLI/CommonCli/commonSflow.tcl

scripts/testSuite/UTA/CLI/CommonCli/commonRoutePolicyDisplay.tcl

scripts/testSuite/networkSecurity/802dot1x/802dot1xBasicFunctionality/802dot1xSuppliSuccessAuth.tcl

scripts/testSuite/hostAgentFeatures/debugLogging/debugLoggingFeatureTesting/DebugLogging_F_SshErrorMsg.tcl
scripts/testSuite/sdnSTC/Flare/Backup_Restore/Sprint16_tests/Backup_Restore_RestoreModeOFFRestore.tcl
```

Now to parse this I am using the code -

```
<?php

include_once ("db_connection.php");

$xml=simplexml_load_file('info.xml');

foreach($xml->testcase as $var)
    {
        $var=explode('/',$var->script);

        print_r($var);

        $module[] =$var[2];

        $testName[] = end($var);
    }

    $modules = array_unique($module); 

        foreach($modules as $newarr) 
            {
                $newmodules[]=$newarr;
            }
 ?>
```

on the other hand I have a database which has column namde script which contains the same data as the xml has. For this I am using the code -

```
<?php

include_once ("db_connection.php");

$conn = testdb_connect ();

$testType = 'TCL';

$sth = $conn->prepare('SELECT script FROM testcases2 WHERE testcases2.testType = :testType');

$sth->execute(array(':testType' => $testType));

    while($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
  { 
        foreach($row as $key) 
            {
                $var=explode('/', $key);

                print_r($var);

                $module[] =$var[2];
            } 

  }

$modules = array_unique($module); 

    foreach($modules as $newarr) 
        {
            $newmodules[]=$newarr;
        }
 ?>
```

In both cases, the output of `print_r($var);` is same which is like - [output](http://pastebin.com/VVCKfCBa).

The problem is here that when I run my my_sql code I get no error but with the PDO I get this `undefined index 2 error`.

what is wrong with the PDO code ?
please guide.

Comment: try $module[] = (!empty($var[2]) ? $var[2] : ''); may be index 2 is blank

Comment: `$module[] =$var[2];` This `$var[2]` does not exist. Check whats inside $var.

Comment: print_r($var); output is like [var](http://pastebin.com/VVCKfCBa)

Comment: @RakeshSharma it worked like magic.

What did you do :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try `$module[] = (!empty($var[2]) ? $var[2] : '');` may be index 2 is blank so showing an undefined index error or try to check your `$var[2]`